# Adding subview to UINavigationController causes rootViewController to disappear on modal dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a view controller in a custom UINavigationController (I have only added a CAGradientLayer to the background). The view controller has a collection view with IGListKit in which a cell can present a view that I add as a subview to the navigation controller. Up until there everything works as expected but when I present a new modal view controller by tapping a UIBarButtonItem and close it with

> self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

The navigation controller is suddenly empty and the root view controller that presented it is no longer in the view hierarchy. So I truly have no idea why adding the subviews to the navigation controller is causing this and how I can fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Could u share the view hierarchy as it's supposed to be so we can help. TBH I'm confused.

Comment: You shouldn't add a subview to the `UINavigationController` from the embedded view controller. You should either add the subview to the view controller inside the `UINavigationController` or present a modal view controller (e.g. `present(modalViewController, animated: true)`).

Comment: @Paolo Thank you! I didn't knew that.

Comment: @HossamGhareeb I know, sorry for being so confusing but yeah Paolo's answer is right I'm adding the subview from the view embedded in the Navigation Controller.

Comment: **If looking for the answer. Check Paolo's answer. He's right. [CLOSED]**